# How to parse two-dimensional checkbox name into JSON with matching indices?

Tags: javascript, json, regex, forms

One of our clients' sites has a form that we hijack and submit via AJAX. Recently we got a request to have it support a fluid list of checkboxes with predefined indices in the name - and I'm a little stumped as to how to properly parse this into an array.

Here's an example:

```
<li><input type="checkbox" name="group[69][4096]" /> Thin</li>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="group[69][8192]" /> Oily</li>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="group[69][16384]" /> Dry</li>
```

The first- and second-level indices are going to change on a regular basis, so they can't be hard-coded. How can I create a two-dimensional javascript array and place these values under the same keys?

For obvious reasons I don't want to use `eval()`, and I tried my hand at regex but I'm afraid it isn't my strong suit. I got close - `.+\[([0-9]+)\]\[([0-9]+)\]` will match the string on http://regexr.com/ - but it doesn't seem to work in js for some reason. At least, I can't get it to return the captured groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could reduce the inputs into a 2d array by parsing each input's name with this regexp `/group\[(\d*?)\]\[(\d*?)\]/`:

```js
const inputs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('[name^="group"]'));

const grid = inputs.reduce((grid, input) => {
  const [, y, x] = input.name.match(/group\[(\d*?)\]\[(\d*?)\]/);
  grid[y] = grid[y] || [];
  grid[y][x] = input.value;
  return grid;
}, []);

console.log(grid);
```

```html
<input name="group[0][0]" value="0,0"/>
<input name="group[0][1]" value="0,1"/>
<input name="group[0][2]" value="0,2"/>
<input name="group[0][3]" value="0,3"/>
<input name="group[0][4]" value="0,4"/>

<input name="group[1][0]" value="1,0"/>
<input name="group[1][1]" value="1,1"/>
<input name="group[1][2]" value="1,2"/>
<input name="group[1][3]" value="1,3"/>
<input name="group[1][4]" value="1,4"/>

<input name="group[2][0]" value="2,0"/>
<input name="group[2][1]" value="2,1"/>
<input name="group[2][2]" value="2,2"/>
<input name="group[2][3]" value="2,3"/>
<input name="group[2][4]" value="2,4"/>
```